# JQuery AJAX Get call fails on IIS but works on Development Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an AJX get call that I use in an MVC3 app.  Below is the call.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetEmailByAdvanced", "CustomerEmails")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: cqvdata,
    success: function (data) {
       //called when successful
       var emails = "";
       $.each(data, function (index, contact) {
           $('#BCCText').tagit('createTag', contact.Email)
       });
       return false;
   },
   error: function (e) {
      //called when there is an error
      alert("Error occurred");
   }
});
```

cqvdata is the serialized form.  On my development server running on my computer this call works fine and I get results.  When I deploy it to Windows Server 2008 R2 it returns an error.

Comment: What is the error? Are there any cucture dependent data in your cqvdata? e.g datetime, decimals, etc?

Comment: I found that the error is 414 Request URL is too long.  I need to send the serialized form data so I don't know if there is some seting I can adjust on IIS?

Comment: It is possible that some date time data could come across in the data depending on the query the people try to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any way to deal with the error 414.  Looking around on the net it seems like the answer usually was that you should use a post with data that large so it comes across differently.  I made that change and now it runs fine.